# Multiple selections from one shapefile

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have two shapefiles, Country and Blocks.  I need to run a very basic selection to find out what blocks intersect the country shapes.  But, the country shapefile has 250+ countries and I need to do this for each row.  The output is a list (ideally a .txt file) of one of the attributes of the block shapefile.  I'm trying to automate this so I don't have to query each country then run the intersection manually.  I'd like to run a Python script or make a model builder, but I don't know how to automate going from one row to the next.

Comment: You should look into [Iterate Feature Selection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Selection/00400000000s000000/). Welcome to GIS.SE!

Comment: Thanks Paul, I was able to reas about it but I can;t find it in the tool box.  Any help on finding it?

Comment: It's a model only tool; hence, it can only be found in model builder.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do an intersect or identity and then use either frequency or summary statistics to sort the results?

Intersect / Identity will join the tables so values from both shapefiles will be accessible and then Frequency / Summary Statistics to reduce the results into just the unique combinations of countries and blocks. Output is a table which can be exported to CSV.

I have also done similar using a search cursor and then get the object id's, make a layer using a query (ObjectID = value) to isolate just the single block and then select layer by location, get count... just remember to delete the layer each time you've finished with it.

Either method will produce a result it just depends on what you want to do with the block/country combination and if you have access to INFO/Advanced level of license.

Comment: +1; the OP appears to be a beginner with ModelBuilder/Python, so this is the way to go. No need to complicate things when running two simple tools will do.